# Matlab: how to read data of different type (string and integer) from string

Tags: matlab

Input:
str = 'str1Name_str1Value_var1Name_var1Value_var2Name_var2Value';

Desire output:
output = {'str1Value', [var1Value], [var2Value]};

I used sscanf function when there was need to extract only integers from the string, it works perfectly. The problem appeared when I wanted to extract some strings and integers from the same input string. The input string has some known pattern (i.e. str1Name, var1Name, etc).

I tried to use regexp, textscan functions but without success:(

Any idea how to do it? I would be extremely appreciate.

EDIT:
Additional example of input string:
str = 'PCNAME_MYPC_OS_UNIX_RAM_4096_NUMCPU_8';

desire output:
output= {'MYPC','UNIX', [4096], [8]};

I will be also satisfied when the output will contain only string, then it would look as follow:
output= {'MYPC','UNIX', '4096', '8'}; -> str2num should does the rest of job

Comment: can you provide a more complete/representative input?

Comment: `textscan` and `sscanf` should be more than sufficient to accomplish this. Please update your question with a representative data string along with what you have already tried.

Comment: @Benoit_11 I edited my origin post by adding more info

Comment: so do you need more help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Since the output seems to be generated by taking every other element from the input separated by an underscore, let's use [strsplit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html?refresh=true) to split that string and extract every component, then indexing to access them and form the output:

```
Input = 'PCNAME_MYPC_OS_UNIX_RAM_4096_NUMCPU_8';

A = strsplit(Input,'_')
```

`A` is now a cell array that looks like this:

```
    A = 

  Columns 1 through 5

    'PCNAME'    'MYPC'    'OS'    'UNIX'    'RAM'

  Columns 6 through 8

    '4096'    'NUMCPU'    '8'
```

So fetch every other element to form the output:

```
Output = A(2:2:end)
```

Which gives:

```
Output = 

    'MYPC'    'UNIX'    '4096'    '8'
```